# Problemas com Semáforos (Produtor/Consumidor)

Tags: java, thread, semáforo

Olá! Estou tentando resolver o Problema do Produtor/Consumidor usando semaforos, mas estou com dificuldades.
Estou usando uma thread para produtor e outra para o consumidor, mas acho que o programa está inicializando o produtor e não está fazendo o mesmo com o consumidor. Poderiam me dizer onde está o problema? Muito obrigado!

```
//Classe Principal
public class Principal {      

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 100;
    Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore vazio = new Semaphore(N);
    Semaphore cheio = new Semaphore(0);
    Fila fl = new Fila();

    Produtor produtor = new Produtor(mutex, vazio, cheio, fl);
    Consumidor consumidor = new Consumidor(mutex, vazio, cheio, fl);

    produtor.run();
    consumidor.run();
  }
}

//Classe do Produtor
public class Produtor extends Thread {
  Fila fl;
  Semaphore mutex, vazio, cheio;

  public Produtor(Semaphore mutex, Semaphore vazio, Semaphore cheio, Fila fl){
    this.mutex = mutex;
    this.vazio = vazio;
    this.cheio = cheio;
    this.fl = fl;
}

public void run(){
    int item;        
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep( ( int ) ( Math.random() * 3000 ) );
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Produtor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        item = aleatorio(0, 99);
        this.vazio.down();
        this.mutex.down();
        this.fl.insere(item);
        this.mutex.up();
        this.cheio.up();
    }

}

  public int aleatorio(int minimo, int maximo) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
  }
}

//Classe do Consumidor
public class Consumidor extends Thread {
  Fila fl;
  Semaphore mutex, vazio, cheio;

  public Consumidor(Semaphore mutex, Semaphore vazio, Semaphore cheio, Fila fl){
    this.mutex = mutex;
    this.vazio = vazio;
    this.cheio = cheio;
    this.fl = fl;
}

public void run() {
    int item;        
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep( ( int ) ( Math.random() * 3000 ) );
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        this.cheio.down();
        this.mutex.down();
        item = (int)this.fl.remove();
        this.mutex.up();
        this.vazio.up();
        System.out.println(item);
    }
  }
} 

//Classe do Semáforo
public class Semaphore {
  private int count = 0;

  public Semaphore(int initVal) {
    count = initVal;
  }

  public synchronized void down() {
    if (count > 0){
        count--;
    } else {
        try {        /* esperar até que count > 0 */
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            System.out.println("erro");
        }  
    }

  }

  public synchronized void up() {
    count++;
    notify(); /* acordar quem estiver em espera */
  } 
}

//Classe Fila para armazenar os elemenetos
public class Fila<T> {
  private List<T> objetos = new LinkedList<T>();

  public void insere(T t){
    this.objetos.add(t);
  }

  public T remove(){
    return this.objetos.remove(0);
  }

  public boolean vazia(){
    return this.objetos.size() == 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta executando a thread pelo método `run`, ou seja, vai executar o código desse método na thread atual sem criar uma nova thread (como qualquer outro método). Portanto o `run` do consumidor somente irá executar quando o `run` do produtor terminar, ou seja, nunca nesse exemplo.

Deveria usar o método `start` que cria uma nova thread e executa o `run` nessa nova thread, retornando do `start` na thread atual:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    produtor.start();   // executa o run numa nova thread
    consumidor.start();
}
```

*Informação adicional*: em vez de extender a Thread é mais indicado implementar o Runnable e passar ele no construtor da Thread:

```
class Produtor implementes Runnable {
    ...
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
    Produtor produtor = new Produtor(...);
    Thead produtorThread = new Thread(produtor);
    produtorThread.start();
```

Mais informações: [Threads](http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/6955/Cap-9-Threads-Segmentos.html)

Update: com o uso de Lambda, principalmente para funções menos complicadas não é necessário criar uma classe dedicada:

```
    Thead produtorThread = new Thread( () -> {
        // comandos a serem executados
        } );
    produtorThread.start();
```

ou, usando uma referência a um método <sub>(meu preferido)</sub>:

```
public class Principal {
...
    Thread produtorThread = new Thread(Principal::metodo); // ou this::metodo para métodos não-static
    produtorThread.start();
...
private static void metodo() {
    // comandos a serem executados na Thread
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Carlos.

Comment: Sim, muito boa a explicação. Obrigado!